# Not able to find any pattern for $4T(n/2)+n^2 n^{1/2}$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I have tried my best but I'm not able to find any pattern for the $n^2n^{1/2}$ part. This question must be solved  iteratively and I get totally clueless after two iteration.s I've to find tight bound in big-O.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Note also our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers), and the many questions about [tag:recurrence-relation].

Comment: Please read about master's theorem

Comment: @HUDATARIQL1F11BSCS2330 You keep writing "underroot" -- what do you mean by that? It's not a standard mathematical term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: Isn't $n^2n^{1/2}=n^{5/2}$?

Comment: @DavidRicherby underroot x = the expression x, under the root, i.e., $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That's just "root-$x$".

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens when you expand the recurrence:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= n^{5/2} + 4(n/2)^{5/2} + 4^2(n/2^2)^{5/2} + 4^3(n/2^3)^{5/2} + \cdots \\ &=
n^{5/2} \left(1 + \frac{4}{2^{5/2}} + \left(\frac{4}{2^{5/2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{4}{2^{5/2}}\right)^3 + \cdots \right).
\end{align*}
$$
Since $4/2^{5/2} = 1/\sqrt{2} < 1$, the large bracketed expression converges, and so the answer is $T(n) = \Theta(n^{5/2})$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
 T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^{\frac{5}{2}}
 =
  4^2T(\frac{n}{2^2}) + 4(\frac{n}{2})^{\frac{5}{2}} + n^{\frac{5}{2}}
\end{equation}
On the $k^{th}$ iteration, we get
\begin{equation}
 T(n) =   4^kT(\frac{n}{2^k}) + 
 \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
 4^i (\frac{n}{2^i})^{\frac{5}{2}}
\end{equation}
which terminantes at $k = \log_2 n$
The part $$4^kT(\frac{n}{2^k}) = O(4^{\log_2 n}) = O(n^2)$$
The sum part could be arranged as 
\begin{equation}
  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
 4^i (\frac{n}{2^i})^{\frac{5}{2}}
 =
 n^{\frac{5}{2}}
  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
 4^i (\frac{1}{2^i})^{\frac{5}{2}}
 =
  n^{\frac{5}{2}}
  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
  \Big(
  \frac{4}{2^{\frac{5}{2}}}
  \Big)^{i}
  =
  n^{\frac{5}{2}}
  \frac{1- \big(\frac{4}{2^{\frac{5}{2}}}\big)^k}{1 - (\frac{4}{2^{\frac{5}{2}}})}
\end{equation}
where the last equality comes from realizing that we have a geometric series.
Notice that 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{4}{2^{\frac{5}{2}}} = (\sqrt{2})^{-1}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
 4^i (\frac{n}{2^i})^{\frac{5}{2}}
 =
n^{\frac{5}{2}}
\frac{1 - (\sqrt{2})^{-k}}{1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}
\end{equation}
But algorithm terminates at $k = \log_2 n$ so
\begin{equation}
  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
 4^i (\frac{n}{2^i})^{\frac{5}{2}}
 =
 O(
n^{\frac{5}{2}}
\frac{1 - (\sqrt{2})^{-\log_2 n}}{1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}
)
=
O\Big(
\alpha n^{\frac{5}{2}}
(1 - (\sqrt{2})^{-\log_2 n})
 \Big)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha
 =
 \frac{1}{1- \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$
But 
\begin{equation}
 (\sqrt{2})^{-\log_2 n} =
 \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2})^{\log_2 n}} =
 \frac{1}{2^{\log_2 \sqrt{n}}}
 =
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
 4^i (\frac{n}{2^i})^{\frac{5}{2}}
 =
 O(
n^{\frac{5}{2}}
\frac{1 - (\sqrt{2})^{-\log_2 n}}{1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}
)
=
O\Big(
\alpha n^{\frac{5}{2}}
(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})
 \Big)
 =
 O( n^{\frac{5}{2}})
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 T(n) =   \underbrace{4^kT(\frac{n}{2^k})}_{O(n^2)} + 
 \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}
 4^i (\frac{n}{2^i})^{\frac{5}{2}}}_{ O( n^{\frac{5}{2}})}
 =
  O( n^{\frac{5}{2}})
\end{equation}